# Coding a non SEF url

Tags: url

I want to create a non SEF URL for an enhancement functionality. Can someone provide example of how the same can be done in code?

Answer (score 2):

Any url in joomla which is not using **JRoute** method is non SEF url.

For eg.

> http://www.example.com/index.php?option=com_yourcomponent&view=article&id=1&catid=20&Itemid=4

Also if you enable the SEF URLs from global configuration then all the urls will work as sef urls.

Read More : [Search Engine Friendly URLs](https://docs.joomla.org/Search_Engine_Friendly_URLs)